# Localizing other pages in Settings.bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, localization, settings.bundle

I have other pages within my app preferences which are stored as separate files within the settings.bundle.

It has come time to localize my app and I can only seem to get the Root values to localize. I was wondering whether there was a trick?

The following image shows that my second screen is stored within a file called "MyPrefs.plist" and I have created a corresponding named file "MyPrefs.strings" in the en.lproj directory. Mirroring the same naming and location as the Root.plist and Root.strings.

[image]

The values with the Root.plist are converted as expected but not in the extra screen.

Is there any trick to localizing secondary screens with the settings.bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the correct value for **Strings Filename** key in the `MyPrefs.plist` file ?

It should look like:

```
+ iPhone Settings Schema
      Settings Page Title    MyPrefs Title
      Strings Filename       MyPrefs
    + Preferences Items
          ....
```

Comment: Perfect thanks - it was still pointing to Root. I made sure the MyPrefs.plist file had the following before the PreferenceSpecifiers key.

...
<key>StringsTable</key>
<string>MyPrefs</string>
<key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
...